# .lib file is still referenced when project type is changed to dll

Tags: c++, dll

In VS 2013 (C++) in multi-project solution I've changed the type of one project from .lib to .dll. Other projects, which reference this library, are automatically change to reference .dll

I'm getting the following error - it seems that the previous .lib configuration is still referenced somewhere. Any thoughts how to fix this?

```
Error   283 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C..\x64\Debug\File.lib' in '..\Project1\LINK
```

Comment: Did you clean all your projects after the change?

Comment: Jesus Ramos - yes, no help

Comment: Did this change with VS2013? Formerly you always referenced the lib, because it contains the interface declaration. The dll is only used at runtime, at compile time, one uses the lib.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Visual Studio generates an import library when you compile to a DLL. The import library also has a `.lib` extension, but it's not a static library. This file tells the linker how to find the DLL and import the external symbols at run time.

If you don't have `.lib` file, you most likely aren't exporting any symbols. You should use `__declspec(dllexport)` to choose which symbols you want to expose to consumers of your DLL.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But why has the above error appeared and how to fix it?

Comment: You may have renamed the output file or the .lib may be placed in a different location.

Comment: Updated answer, no import library is generated if you don't export any symbols.